# Microphone voltage output - is it AC?

Tags: ac, dc, multimeter, microphone

Can anyone tell me if the output voltage of a microphone (like the type on a webcam) is an AC voltage? And whatever it is, can it be measured on a standard voltmeter?

Thank you.

Comment: The output of a webcam is usually (digital) USB. Please elaborate.

Comment: OK, thank you. Just consider a microphone, then. You attach a battery, you speak, and this gets converted into an output electrical signal which is connected to a speaker. Is this output DC or AC (in that it is a varying signal which depends on the sound or voice)?

Comment: Powered microphones (such as electrets) usually have a DC content on which the AC signal is superimposed.

Comment: @Andyaka Thank you. So, could this be measured by a standard multimeter or must you use an oscilloscope?

Comment: An AC RMS measuring meter will do but be aware that most AC meters expect a continuous signal to be present in order to make a simplified RMS computation based on the assumption that a sine wave is being measured. Sound is much more complex and doesn't look like a sine wave at all most of the time.

Comment: Use an oscilloscope if you want to capture any signal worth looking at. A standard voltmeter will not give you anything useful.

Comment: @KyranF Hi. Thank you for your answer. Yes, I agree with that. I'm seeing nothing at all. I'll have to get an oscilloscope. Thank you.

Comment: @Andyaka Thank you. My meter is a standard type. I think I'll have to use an oscilloscope. Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

The audio signal from a microphone will be AC, with the frequency and amplitude (voltage) of the signal depending on the sound that the microphone is picking up.

For electret microphones, the audio signal will usually also have a DC bias, which can be removed with an AC coupling capacitor.